# Add Metadata to SVG Symbol or Use Element

Tags: svg, sprite

We are using a plugin to combine all SVG icons into several spritesheets. This is so that when the user hovers or focuses an image, there will be no flash while the image is downloaded, as the image is in the same spritesheet as the un-hovered image, and therefore is already downloaded. This also reduces requests, which reduces bandwidth as well as the time the user needs to wait to view the page.

We are currently using a plugin which simply combines all SVG sprites into a single SVG spritesheet, but all the SVGs are directly inside the meta-SVG. We have started moving to `gulp-svgstore`, which puts the SVG's into different `<symbol>`s instead. We then reference the correct icon with a `<use>`.

The problem with this is that, ideally, we want the entire SVG icon in each `<symbol>`, so the icons can be created by designers who (need to) know little about programming. `<use>` elements do not seem to accept things like gradients. They are likely not allowed in the spec, but in practice browsers just ignore them. We had an interesting situation where Internet Explorer 11 was showing the image correctly but the other browsers were not, as the polyfill we were using for `<use>` just plopped the content of the inner SVG into the outer SVG, whereas other browsers actually `<use>`d the inner SVG.

**Is there any way to add metadata like gradients to a `<symbol>` element that is referenced with `<use>`?**

Comment: use elements do accept gradients. Browsers simply have not implemented that part of the specification.

Comment: I thought so. Is this expected to be part of the spec, maybe in SVG 3? Otherwise, is there any way to do this, or will our designers just have to give us a secondary metadata file?

Comment: It's been part of the spec for years. It's hard to implement and pointless since you can put gradients outside symbols.

Comment: Yes, but not if you want the `<symbol>` to be essentially another SVG itself. Regardless, I get your point. We will have to think of another way. Thank you, could you put this into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: My colleague suggested we could put the metadata outside the `<symbol>`. I agree, but we would have to use `cheerio` or something to extract the metadata. I think I will open an issue on `svgstore`.

Comment: So Firefox & Chrome support radial gradients anywhere they lie inside the <use>. Firefox supports linear gradients, inside or outside a <defs>, as long as they are outside any <g>. Chrome doesn't support linear gradients inside of <use> at all. Safari is like Chrome. Additionally, while the other 2 browsers show unknown gradients as transparent, Safari shows them as black. I like showing them as transparent, but I guess showing as black could help with debugging.